# R: Is it possible to add labels to mean_cl_boot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add labels indicating the mean in a jitter plot, I've used the mean_cl_boot function in stat_summary and the means are showing on the plot, but I'd like to add labels showing the actual values and I'm at a bit of a loss.

[Jitter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB6oa.png)

Here's my code

```
lisbondata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(q1b,exage)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot",colour="red") +
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.2) +
  labs(title = "Age distribution between Yes/No votes",
        x = "Vote",
        y = "Age") +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine different stats and geom together. If you have `stat_summary()`, you can combine it with `geom_label()` by setting `geom = "label"`. You can then tell the label to be the mean value, by delaying the assignment of the `label` aesthetic using `after_stat()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_jitter(colour = "grey50") +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", colour = "red"
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_cl_boot",
    geom = "label",
    aes(label = after_stat(scales::number(y))),
    hjust = 1.2
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>